# how can change position of a button over an imagebackground?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

here, I have  taken a view in which  added  image background and  two buttons somehow I am not able to change button's position

```
      <ImageBackground
        style={styles.container}
        resizeMode="cover"
        source={require("../../assets/loginsignup.png")}
      >
        <Button
          style={styles.button}
          title=""
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Login")}
        />
        <Button title="" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Register")} />
        
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
```

and this is the style I have implemented

```
  container: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    position: "relative",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
  },
  button: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 345,
  },
});
```

I tried doing same thing with text inside imagebackground and that works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your styles like this if you want to make your button center horizontally and vertically. Refer [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox) article for more styling options.

```
container: {
    flex : 1,
    position: "relative",
    alignItems : 'center', // Vertically
    justifyContent : 'center', // Horizontally  
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem , i used touchableopacity instead and i could change it , if you want to keep using buttons try to put them inside a view :

```
<View style={{flex:1,alignItems:'where you want'}} 
 //your buttons
  </View>
```

You can use flexDirection column or row too
Tell me if this works